# How can I put the rect of a sprite in the center of the image

Tags: python, pygame, sprite, rect, collider

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iwR60.png)

here is what I have until now, I have draw the rect to keep a track of it, here is the code:

```
class Personagem(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
      def __init__(self,x,y):
            super().__init__()
            self.imagem = pygame.image.load('sprites/frente-parado.bmp')
            self.rect = self.imagem.get_rect()
            self.rect.height = 20
            self.rect.width = 20
            self.rect.centerx = x
            self.rect.centery = y
            self.velocidade_x = 0
            self.velocidade_y = 0
```

I have been looking at similar questions here, a have tried create another rect that starts at the bottom left of the original but then I cant collide it because the sprite ended up with two rects

I appreciate any answer, sorry for bad english

Comment: I would like to improove your own answer without this bruteforce solution, but to do this, I would need to know what x,y are: if it is the topleft corner of the image or an other kind coordinates

Comment: Yes, its que topleft, actually a tried to change x and y to all coordinates of the rect, topleft was the better one.

Answer (score 0):

To center the rect of a sprite in the image, you can use the center attribute of the rect instead of centerx and centery. Here's an updated version of your code that centers the rect:

```
class Personagem(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        super().__init__()
        self.imagem = pygame.image.load('sprites/frente-parado.bmp')
        self.rect = self.imagem.get_rect()
        self.rect.width = 20
        self.rect.height = 20
        self.rect.center = (x, y)
        self.velocidade_x = 0
        self.velocidade_y = 0
```

In this version, the center attribute of the rect is set to the tuple (x, y), which will center the rect in the image. Note that I've also switched the order of the width and height attributes, as it's recommended to set the width before the height when working with pygame.

Comment: `self.rect.center = (x, y)` does exactly the same as `self.rect.centerx = x` `self.rect.centery = y`. So the solution proposed in your answer will not change anything.

Comment: I tried to do it but the rect keep on the top left corner of image, very similar to the image i linked in the question but this time its closer to the character's head, I think that the problem may be in the blit

`per = Personagem(40,40)
tela.blit(per.imagem,per)`

Answer (score 0):

well, I find a way to do it, its a bit ugly but it works

`x = per.rect.topleft[0] - 10`
`y = per.rect.topleft[1] - 10`
`tela.blit(per.imagem,(x,y))`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5RjD.png)

Answer (score 0):

When you initialize `Personagem` you give to it the two variables `x` and `y`. Looking at your first picture, you were giving the topleft corner of the image.
To center the rect on the center of the image you would need to give a `pygame.Rect()` of the image.

```
class Personagem(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, r):
        super().__init__()
        self.imagem = pygame.image.load('sprites/frente-parado.bmp')
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(0,0,20,20)
        self.rect.center = r.center
        self.velocidade_x = 0
        self.velocidade_y = 0
```

`pygame.Rect(0,0,20,20)` creates a rectangle with 20 px in width and 20 px in height, while `self.rect.center = r.center` centers the rect with the rect of the image.

If you prefer, you can also choose to give to `Personagem` two variables `centerx` and `centery` instead and the class would result in

```
class Personagem(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, centerx,centery):
        super().__init__()
        self.imagem = pygame.image.load('sprites/frente-parado.bmp')
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(0,0,20,20)
        self.rect.centerx = centerx
        self.rect.centery = centery
        self.velocidade_x = 0
        self.velocidade_y = 0
```